# Getting a NullPointerException on pop method

Tags: java

I am beginning in Linked Stacks and I was wondering why is this part of the code giving me a NullPointerException. The one thing I want to do in the main driver is to keep adding books until I enter stop when prompted. The push method seems to be working since on the top of the list in the output you can see that the Book - 2 is on top. I've tried to approach it in other ways but it keeps giving me that exact error. *Note I have read the similar questions that appear when I wrote this one but I can't seem to find the problem.*

**Here's the code for both push and pop:**

```
@Override
 public void push(T data)
 {
 Node<T> current = new Node<>(data, top);
 if(count == top.length)
 {
  expandCapacity();   
 }
 current.setNext(top);
 top[count++] = current;

 }
```

*Heres where I am getting the problem pop method*

@Override

```
 public T pop()
 {
 T result;

 if(count == 0 || top == null )
 {
     System.out.println("List is empty");
 }

 result = top[count].getData();
 top =  top[count - 1].getNext();

 return result;
 }
```

**Here's LinkedStack's declarations and constructor**

```
public class LinkedStack<T> implements linkedInterface<T> {

 private int count;
 private Node<T> []top;
 private static final int size = 5;


 public LinkedStack()
 {
     top = (Node<T>[]) (new Node [size]);
     count = 0;

 }
```

**Here's the code of the Node class**

```
public class Node<T> 
{

private T data; 
private Node []next;

public Node(T _data)
{
data = _data;
}
public Node(T _data, Node []_next)
{
data = _data;
next = _next;
}

public T getData()
{
return data;    
}

public void setData(T _data)
{
data = _data;    
}

public Node[] getNext()
{

return next;    

}

public void setNext(Node []_next)
{
 next = _next;   
}

}
```

**Output**

```
Note to stop adding books enter: 'stop' when prompted.
Book-1
Enter title:
title1
author1
ISBN1
10

Do you wish stop adding books? N || stop
n
Book-2
Enter title:
title2
author2
ISBN2
20

Do you wish stop adding books? N || stop
stop
The books in list are:

Title:title2
Author/s: author2
ISBN: ISBN2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
Copies in stock: 20

    at node.LinkedStack.pop(LinkedStack.java:133)
    at node.BookDriver.main(BookDriver.java:85)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 36 seconds)
```

Comment: Please highlight the part where r u getting the issue.

Comment: Can you print value of count and top.size just before you retrieve the data?

Comment: You make a check for top, but continue to "pop" the element any way??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you check for `top` being null, but instead of halting the method by returning, you print a warning and keep going as if it's not null. A few lines later, you access the array and if it is null , kaboom.

Try something like this:

```
 if(count == 0 || top == null )
 {
     System.out.println("List is empty");
     return null; // ADDED THIS LINE!
 }
```

#### Edit

Even if top isn't null, if a null gets added to the list, you're also hosed:

```
top[count].getData()
```

Will throw a NPE if `top[count]` has a null stored in it.

Comment: Your point is valid but will "top" ever be null as its initialized in the constructor?

Comment: @Bohemian This helped since now it dint throw it off like always but now it pointed out the line 136 which is " result = top[count].getData(); "

Comment: @Sudhanshu hmmm. But why goes he check if it's null? Maybe it can become null - who knows.